# CSS variable width element to fill in space

Tags: javascript, css, layout, width

In a form, I would like the input:text to fill the remain space after the label to the form is left and right justified.

The label have number of characters so I can't set a fixed width on the label.

Code example:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>User Info</legend>
<p><label>First Name :</label><input type="text"...></p>
<p><label>Last Name : </label><input type="text"...></p>
<p><label>Completed Email Address :</label><input type="text"...></p>
</fieldset>
```

How can I style the input to fill the remaining space after the text.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can just http://giveupandusetables.com

Comment: @doublep, how would using tables come even close to solving the OP's problem?

Comment: @jeroen: http://pastebin.com/vpXN0TsM.  Should work on all browser, unlike the answer.

Comment: @doublep: yeah, and if you use absolute URLs, it should display nicely in all email clients, too

Comment: doublep is right (sadly), while we wait for every browser to support `display: table;` or some CSS3 flexible box model ... The example lacks `for/id` on `label/input` and you should be careful that the table can be linearized (the pastebin code seems OK).

Comment: @doublep: impressive, that's one I hadn't thought of :-)

Comment: @doublep: Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: Well, the question asked for CSS.

Comment: @doublep: It's still a solution that solves the problem for today's browsers.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: OK, convinced; reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .grid { width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: auto; }
        .row { display: table-row; }
        label.cell { white-space: nowrap; display: table-cell; }
        span.cell { width: 100%; display: table-cell; }
        span.cell input { width: 100%; display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Info</legend>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row"><label class="cell">First Name:</label> <span class="cell"><input type="text" /></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row"><label class="cell">Last Name:</label> <span class="cell"><input type="text" /></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row"><label class="cell">Completed Email Address:</label> <span class="cell"><input type="text" /></span></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Won't work in older browsers.

LE: if you don't need/want/have to support old browsers such as IE 6 and 7, use this code. Otherwise, use JavaScript. Ooor use this code an throw in some JavaScript for IE 6 and 7. Yeah, I think that's the best way to do it :D

Comment: Is there any modern non-IE browser (except IE9) out there that won't make this function if `table-row` container is omitted? I have `table-cell` elements directly under a `table` element and it works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I posted this in a comment first, but was advised to post as an answer instead.  This is not a CSS solution, but a table-based one.  However, it should work on all browsers (though I didn't test this).  `span` inside label's `td` is needed to workaround IE's bug of not applying `white-space: nowrap` to table cells.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="1"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">First name:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width:100%"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="1"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">Last name:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width:100%"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="1"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">Completed Email Address:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width:100%"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using floats for the left (or right) side, and "block formatting context"ifying the right side items.

[Read about block formatting contexts in css at the YUIblog](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uS3Cv/1/

Comment: How does this meet the OP's requirement of "filling the remaining space after the label"?

Comment: Yup :) Nice one. How backward-compatible is it?

Comment: IE6 has problems when the BFC-ified element has margin/padding/border (BFC drops below the floats) or when the BFC's content grows too wide, in this case you may use three elements instead of one: <div class="block-formatting-context"><div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;"><div style="padding:123px;">. I don't know if it could be simplified.